# Day and Night system, checking if light even when not getting light?

Tags: c#, game-engine

I have coded a day and night system for my game, but I am having an issue with one of the methods. I have coded it well so far except for one method. Here is the full code:

```
using Plus.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Plus.Roleplay.GameEnvironment
{
    class GameEnvironmentHandler
    {
        private List<TimeSpan> _darkTimes;
        private List<TimeSpan> _lightTimes;

        public GameEnvironmentHandler()
        {
            _darkTimes = new List<TimeSpan>
            {
                new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0),
                new TimeSpan(19, 30, 0),
                new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0),
                new TimeSpan(20, 30, 0),
                new TimeSpan (21, 0, 0)
            };

            _lightTimes = new List<TimeSpan>
            {
                new TimeSpan(06, 0, 0),
                new TimeSpan(06, 30, 0),
                new TimeSpan(07, 0, 0),
                new TimeSpan(07, 30, 0),
                new TimeSpan (08, 0, 0)
            };
        }

        public bool IsGettingDark()
        {
            return RoleplayHelper.IsTimeOfDayBetween(DateTime.Now,
                _darkTimes.First(), _darkTimes.Last());
        }

        public bool IsGettingLight()
        {
            return RoleplayHelper.IsTimeOfDayBetween(DateTime.Now,
                _lightTimes.First(), _lightTimes.Last())
                || RoleplayHelper.IsTimeOfDayBetween(DateTime.Now, 
                _lightTimes.First(), _darkTimes.Last());
        }
    }
}
```

The method I am having issues with is IsGettingLight(), I have coded it to check if the time is inbetween the first and last light times, but what if its after the last time it starts getting light, and before the first time it gets dark, how can I check if its neither getting dark, dark, or getting light? I know its something to do with removing a bit of time off the first dark time, but what exactly do I remove, and how?

Comment: Wouldn't that be between `_lightTimes.Last()` and `_darkTimes.First()`? Not sure I understand the question, or why you're not asking a similar question about the times between `_darkTimes.Last()` and `_lightTimes.First()`

Comment: Also, not sure `TimeSpan` is the right object to use... It's supposed to represent a span of time, not a specific time. For a specific time, you should use the `DateTime` object and compare the hours, minutes and seconds part of that with `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`

Comment: @RufusL I can't use TimeOfDay because the two times may overlap after midnight into another day. What I said (between _lightTimes.Last() and _darkTimes.First()) I mean't it would be light for all the time it wasn't getting dark or getting light also? I am trying to get every minute of the day where it will be light.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I also didn't realize that `TimeOfDay` is actually a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Added an answer that uses `TimeOfDay` and should work even after midnight :). Not sure if it covers everything you wanted, but basically it captures the transistions from dark->light and light->dark, the times when it's fully light or dark, and then these can be combined to determine if it's either light or dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
// firstLight starts at 5:30
var firstLight = new TimeSpan(5, 30, 0);

// fullLight start at 8:00
var fullLightStart = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);

// first Darkness starts at 18:30
var firstDark = new TimeSpan(18, 30, 0);

// fullDarkness starts at 21:00
var fullDarkStart = new TimeSpan(21, 0, 0);
```

Then, to see where you're at in the day, you can compare the current `TimeOfDay` with the values above:

```
var currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

var IsGettingLight = currentTime >= firstLight && currentTime < fullLightStart;
var IsFullLight = currentTime >= fullLightStart && currentTime < firstDark;
var IsGettingDark = currentTime >= firstDark && currentTime < fullDarkStart;
var IsFullDark = currentTime >= fullDarkStart || currentTime < firstLight;

var IsLight = IsGettingLight || IsFullLight;
var IsDark = IsGettingDark || IsFullDark;
```

Comment: Great! I did just notice one problem with `IsFullDark` and fixed it above (it was including `firstLight`).

Comment: I did notice that myself and fixed it. Thank you. :)

Comment: This problem is a bit more tricky than I expected but this solution fixed it. Thank you! +1